# Django: How to get an object with a file name

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model with a FileField:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='files'
    )
```

What would be the best approach for getting an object of the model from the databse with the name of the file?

Something like:

```py
try:
    foo = Foo.objects.get(
        file__name='bar.csv',
    )
except Foo.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    return something()
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
    return something_else()
process(foo)
```

I guess I could add a `file_name` field into the model and setting `self.file_name = self.file.name` in `Foo.save()`, but that seems cumbersome..?

Comment: `foo.file.name`

Comment: Or are you asking what is the best way to query the databse?

Comment: @JerieWang, yes, the best way to query the database. I'll clarify the question.